# React map is duplicating DOM Elements

Tags: html, reactjs, spring, web, frontend

I have the following issue:

I am building a web application, BackEnd in spring and FrontEnd in React.

Now I am adding a feature that shows how many products are in the cart while the client is clicking on "buy". The problem is that when I do a map to get the API in the dom tree, it seems like is duplicating the element.

Images:
[Bug: "Carrinho ( )" is being duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPCAP.png)

Note:
I am consuming two APIs

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Row,
  CardBody,
  Container,
 } from 'reactstrap';



import api from '../../resources/api_produtos';
import apiCart from '../../resources/api_cart';
import axios from 'axios';


const Main = () =>{

  
  const[product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const[cart, setCart] = useState([]);
 

  const fetchData = () =>{
    const productApi = api.get('');
    const cartApi = apiCart.get('');

    axios.all([productApi, cartApi]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) =>{
        const allProductData = allData[0].data;
        const allDataCart = allData[1].data;
      

        setProduct(allProductData);
        setCart(allDataCart);
       
        console.log(allDataCart);
      })
    )
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchData()
  }, [])



   return (

    <div>      
 
          <div className="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white d-flex justify-content-between">           
          <div>
            <strong>Game Store</strong>
          </div>
          <div>
              {cart.map(carrinho =>(
              <div key={carrinho.id}>
                <div>
                  Carrinho ( {carrinho.amount} ) HERE IS BEING DUPLICATED
                </div>
              </div>                 
              ))}

            </div>  
          </div>
       
 
    <Container>
      <div className="jumbotron mt-3"><h1>Produtos</h1></div>
      
      {product.map(produto => (
      
      <div className="card mb-3">  
    
          <div key={produto.id}className="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span>
              Id: {produto.id}
            </span>
            <div>
                      <nav>
                          <form method="POST" action={"http://localhost:8080/comprar/" + produto.id}>
                            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary"  value="Comprar" ></input>
                          </form>
                      </nav>
            </div>
          
          </div>
        
        <CardBody>
        <Row>
          <div className="col-12 col-sm-8 mb-3">  
            <div className="row">       
              <div key={produto.id}>
                      <div >
                        Nome: {produto.name}
                      </div> 
                      <div > 
                        Preço: R$ {produto.price}                          
                      </div>   
              </div>   
            </div>     
          </div> 

            <div className="col-12 col-md-4">            
                  <figure key={produto.id}>
                    <img className="img-thumbnail"src={produto.image} />
                  </figure>
              
            </div>    

            </Row>
          </CardBody>
        
        </div>           
              ))}

       
    </Container> 
    </div>
  );
}


export default Main;
```

And this is how the API "Cart" looks like:

```
[{"amount":"7"},[{"id":12,"name":"Mortal Kombat XL","price":69.99,"score":150,"image":"https://images-americanas.b2w.io/produtos/01/00/offers/01/00/item/126077/6/126077695_1GG.png"},{"id":12,"name":"Mortal Kombat XL","price":69.99,"score":150,"image":"https://images-americanas.b2w.io/produtos/01/00/offers/01/00/item/126077/6/126077695_1GG.png"},{"id":12,"name":"Mortal Kombat XL","price":69.99,"score":150,"image":"https://images-americanas.b2w.io/produtos/01/00/offers/01/00/item/126077/6/126077695_1GG.png"},{"id":12,"name":"Mortal Kombat XL","price":69.99,"score":150,"image":"https://images-americanas.b2w.io/produtos/01/00/offers/01/00/item/126077/6/126077695_1GG.png"},{"id":12,"name":"Mortal Kombat XL","price":69.99,"score":150,"image":"https://images-americanas.b2w.io/produtos/01/00/offers/01/00/item/126077/6/126077695_1GG.png"},{"id":12,"name":"Mortal Kombat XL","price":69.99,"score":150,"image":"https://images-americanas.b2w.io/produtos/01/00/offers/01/00/item/126077/6/126077695_1GG.png"},{"id":12,"name":"Mortal Kombat XL","price":69.99,"score":150,"image":"https://images-americanas.b2w.io/produtos/01/00/offers/01/00/item/126077/6/126077695_1GG.png"}]]
```

How do I fix this duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the response object from your cart API.
It's bad-formed, since your BE is returning an array which gives no sense since the response includes one single cart.

So, the map function iterate over an array, modifying its content by the callback, place them in a new array, and then returns it.
So essentially you are trying to modify the obj on the index 0, which is and obj with the "amount" field, and then, you are trying to map an array at index 1.

So you have to update your response from the BE, something like that:

```json
{
    "id": "cart_id",
    "items": []
}
```

Which has more sense compared with yours. Note that since items is an array you don't need the "amount" field, you can access it with `carrinho.items.length` for instance. Then render it with

```js
<div key={carrinho.id}>
    <div>Carrinho ({carrinho.items.length})</div>
</div>
```